# How can I handle different server and different to connect Asp.net Web API using linq and lambda

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Previously, My older API version is connecting different server and database  from code side. I called sql query, views and store procedures directly asking from client which server and database need to connect and then return respective JSON results to clients.
For now, I would like to convert Linq and Lambda expression and also I would like to use edmx and entity framework .
Please kindly response me if there any suggestion about this.

Comment: the connection string isnt handled by the query, but by the context. Either pass a connection to the context or build a connection string and pass that to the context.

Comment: thanks ur suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Because you already have a database use entity framework database first that will generate your models automatically and will create a Super Class called Dbcontext where you will find all the database tables and later on you will use LINQ to get data from Dbcontext.

useful link [Ef databasefirst](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db).
 search for **entity framework database first** this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to connect edmx connection dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for ur link.